# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Politics breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                 20         19
Users destroyed                                  33          0
Users deleted                                    11          0
Users contacted                                  40          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            30      2,057
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                0      1,771
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue          4      1,371
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                0        251
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 1      1,503
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue                0      3,685
Tags merged                                       3          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             3          2
Tag synonyms created                              3          0
Questions unprotected                             7          4
Questions reopened                               53        105
Questions protected                             113         53
Questions migrated                               56          1
Questions flagged⁴                                0        787
Questions closed                                297        597
Question flags handled⁴                         498        289
Posts unlocked                                    8         21
Posts undeleted                                  19         57
Posts locked                                     17        103
Posts deleted⁵                                  358      1,070
Posts bumped                                      0         88
Escalations to the CM team                        2          0
Comments undeleted                              363          0
Comments flagged                                  1      2,415
Comments deleted⁶                             9,708      2,417
Comment flags handled                         2,193        223
Answers flagged                                   0      1,390
Answer flags handled                            716        674
All comments on a post moved to chat            165          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: If the same user is suspended twice in a year, then is that counted as a single suspension or as two on this overview?

Comment: Two, @martinTournoij

Comment: Right, that's what I would expect, bu the label "Users suspended" suggests otherwise. Would probably be a good idea to tweak that label for next year.

Comment: How would community do "Answer flags handled"? Or is that some (spam?) auto-system too?

Comment: @user4012 If [6 users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor) flag a post as spam the [Community user](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) will automatically mark the flag as valid, delete the post and lock it so that only moderators can edit or undelete it. This will no doubt mark the flag as handled in the system.