# How to handle 'arguments from authority'

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, references

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority) an argument from authority or *argumentum ab auctoritate* is a fallacy "in which a claimed authority's support is used as evidence for an argument's conclusion".

I just read a comment in which a user dismissed articles from The Hill and the BBC because, and I [quote](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/38279/why-is-there-so-little-public-outcry-about-the-shutdown#comment146404_38292):

> Trump is consistently saying that. He has access to classified information, likely analyzed by his senior advisers. Simply google search on Trump would give you.

This is quite obviously an argument from authority and it easily dismisses any other answer based on evidence **without providing any verifiable evidence itself**. How should such comments and answers relying on such fallacies be handled?

1. Should such comments be flagged and consequently removed?
2. Should answers relying solely on such arguments be removed or merely voted down?

Comment: Is it strange that I knew who the user was just from your quote, without even reading the answer in question?

Comment: @F1Krazy that's a good thing, right? That means you'd associate such arguments with only a few users. It's the exception rather than the norm.

Comment: That particular user is insistant that literally only what the trump administration says is true and everything else is not an official source and therefore opinion. I don't know if you can argue against that other then disengaging.

Comment: @Magisch you don't have to argue with anyone who insists that your sources are not "official."  No one has to trust your sources.  And you don't have to convince anyone to trust them.  If someone thinks you are providing sources which cannot be trusted, they can downvote and you can both move on.  But the point is that if you do provide a source, that source acts as a reference regardless of whether that's a good reference or not.  At that point it's not *just* an opinion.

Comment: When it's reached the point that someone uses an argument from authority to justify arguments from authority, when someone says anything someone says must be reliable unless they're convicted of a crime, when someone argues that any questioning of the unsubstantiated statements of an elected official is "close to treason," I fail to see how that's even [participating in good faith](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3040/a-full-and-objective-description-of-good-faith) for the purposes of this site.

Comment: Argument from authority example (3 minute video): https://youtu.be/WGpcsYr-mOU

Comment: @Michael_B I'm not sure if that qualifies. An argument from authority relies on authority to support a claim. The man in the video disputes mister Shapiro's authority regarding statements he made (in a speech or book?). As for this question, it primarily asks how to respond to such arguments, please write an answer if you have an idea.

Comment: The questioner is a student who is saying that Mr. Shapiro is not qualified to comment on matters of sociology or psychology because he doesn't have a Ph.D. in sociology or psychology. That's the argument from authority. In response, Mr. Shapiro says that his comments should stand on their merits.

Comment: He also points to the yarmulke on his head and states that, when he makes his arguments, he never cites to the Bible, despite the fact that he's a very religious person. He doesn't do that, he claims, because that would be an argument from authority.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When it comes to identifying the "argument from authority" fallacy, then there is one thing one needs to pay attention to: Is the author using the authority as a source for a *fact* or for an *opinion*?

For example, let's take these two statements:

1. According to this article from DailyDogMagazine, cats are the worst pets of all.
2. According to this article from DailyDogMagazine, domestic cats cause an economic damage of several million dollar each year in form of scratched furniture.

The first is an argument form authority. "It's the opinion of a source I believe in, so it must be correct". This is always a fallacious argument. No source has ultimate moral authority, no matter how much you trust it. You have to check what facts they based their conclusions on and if their chain of reasoning is correct. If you want to convince someone that they are right, you need to prove that you did that work.

The second argument is a source providing a fact. Now the question is whether or not we should believe that fact. Is DailyDogMagazine a reputable source? Are they renowned for providing reliable information based on unbiased research? Or were they caught spreading misinformation or cherry-picking in the past? While no source should always be considered 100% reliable, the past reputation of a source is a good indicator for how much weight their information should have.

Now what should we do if we identify an answer which is based on argument form authority or information from untrustworthy sources?

**Downvote it.** When readers can not rely on the answer being correct, then "the answer is not useful", just as the tooltip of the downvote button says. You might post **one** comment where you explain that you downvoted the answer because you don't think it does a good job at convincing you that it is correct.

When you feel that the answer has absolutely no merit because *everything* in the answer is based on unsourced arguments from authority, you can consider to flag the answer as "very low quality" to put it into the review queue and let the community decide whether to delete it or not. But content deletion should be the ultima ratio. The preferred way to handle bad answers should always be to give the author the opportunity to fix their answer. Deletion should only be considered when an answer contains absolutely no useful content and is definitely unsalvageable.

Regarding comments which try to defend a bad answer by using arguments form authority: It is best to just ignore them. Politics Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum. When someone is convinced of their views, then it is not your job to convert them. It is their job to convince you that their answer is correct. If they fail to convince you, just keep your downvote and move on. Arguing just takes everyone's time and nerves and often leads nowhere:

[image: someone is wrong on the internet]

<sub>image source: [xkcd](https://www.xkcd.com/386/)</sub>

Comment: So you're saying outside of downvoting every time they make this fallacious claim, there is nothing we can do? I reckon seeing an answer or comment like that, regardless if downvoted or not, is likely to reflect extremely poorly on stack exchange for being allowed to remain. If you look back at the hot water IPS got into with question titles, I think if anyone starts a feud about one of these answers, it'll be a lot worse.

Comment: Nice answer, but you don't mention voting to delete such answers. Should we merely down vote or should we also vote to delete such answer?

Comment: @JJJ from the current trajectory at some point the automated answer ban will kick in

Comment: @Magisch sure, but I'm not asking about this user specifically. Other users sometimes do the same. Once you have 1000 rep you can look through the low-quality queue. It's not that uncommon at all.

Comment: @JJJ I've only really personally seen this behavior in the extreme from a couple users on the site. One is currently suspended, and another probably 1-2 more posts away from a permanent answer ban. So eh.

Comment: @Magisch that means the system's working, [over 1300 posts were deleted last year](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3740/18862). ;)

Comment: @JJJ I added another paragraph regarding deletion

Comment: +1. This is 99% awesome. My only concern is about cases where a person's expertise is valuable as opinion. For example, I pay my doctor a lot of money for their opinion about how to improve my health. Their authority doesn't make their claims true in a formal logical sense, but their experience and expertise do mean that their opinion is likely better than my own.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I was involved in the quoted discussion, [this particular comment was addressed to me](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88735/discussion-on-answer-by-smallchess-are-there-any-theories-as-to-why-there-is-so).

I agree with Philipp's answer: such answers/comments should be downvoted. I would like to add that I think it's useful to expose the contradictions that such fallacies entail, in order to make it clear that it's not the opinion which is downvoted, it's the flawed reasoning. This is important not to somehow convince the author (this would be pointless obviously), but because this way future readers can understand why the answer or comment is unhelpful.

Comment: Note that comments cannot be downvoted, which is one of the reasons that "answers as comments" are strongly discouraged, and also a reason that "highly upvoted comment" isn't really a significant statement of quality.

Comment: Oh right I forgot.

Answer (score -12):

I think people here are **overreacting**. There was no rule here disallowing me from using the official White House sources as a reference. I don't think this site is meant only for Democrats, so people shouldn't have downvoted me just because I was not a supporter.

Please remember the US economy under Trump is the most successful in the world; highest GDP, growing employment rate, strong US dollars, terrorism defeated, good stock market performance. Trump did all of that, they are facts you can't deny them. If you don't believe the US government, who else would you believe? Venezuela? Russia? China?

Everything people talk negatively about Trump in the press are **rumour**. Russian link? Has Trump been impeached? In the US, everybody including the Trump are given **benefit of the doubt**. Unless Trump has proven guilty legally, we must assume he is a great president and therefore his words are reliable.

Do you believe your doctor? If your doctor informs you that your are physically fine. Would you dismiss your doctor because "*without providing any verifiable evidence itself*"???

Would you reject your lawyer because your lawyer was not able to provide "*verifiable evidence itself*"?

While we appreciate freedom of speech in the US, the President is always the authority of our country.

Comment: [2018 was pretty bad for stocks, actually](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/12/31/investing/dow-stock-market-today/index.html). I'd point out more inaccuracies but I have been advised not to.

Comment: @JJJ the market was strong overall. Look at Apple.

Comment: `the President is always the authority of our country` So you accepted everything Obama said when he was the President?

Comment: "Would you reject your lawyer because your lawyer was not able to provide verifiable evidence itself?" Yes, because if he tells me X is legal but refuses to show me the relevant clauses that make it legal, he's either guessing or outright lying. Either way, it's very sketchy and I can't risk trusting him. As for doctors, they will always run tests on you before declaring whether you're "fine" or not - that's the evidence.

Comment: "Unless Trump has proven guilty legally, we must assume he is a great president and therefore his words are reliable." - LOL - That's not how that works. Obama hasn't been convicted of any crimes yet either. Does that make him a great President and his statements reliable?

Comment: @JJJ Well, sort of. As of today's close, the DJIA is up 39.8% and S&P 500 is up 28.6% from election day 2016. The loss of 2018 specifically was due to mostly two factors: 1) the gains of the 15 months from Nov 2016 through Jan 2018 were absurd and the market corrected to more reasonable levels and 2) a short-lived panic in Dec '18 due to Fed rate rise, changing Congress, and gov't shut down that has already completely reversed. This is not to say the extreme gains of late '16-early '18 were Trump's doing, though. They were more a reaction to Clinton losing than anything else.

Comment: @F1Krazy To play devil's advocate, there often aren't any relevant clauses to say that something is legal. It's usually more the absence of relevant clauses making it illegal that makes it legal.

Comment: @SmallChess "The stock market is doing well" does not lead to the conclusion "the President's statements are reliable." That's a non-sequitur. Also, the USD is actually down a bit from where it was over the couple of years prior to Trump's election (though not by a lot.)

Comment: *"Trump did all of that, they are facts you can't deny them."* Yes I can, quite easily actually. He can't have, he doesn't have the power (3 branches of government for starters, remember?). Also, many of those things have actually show reduced growth since he took power. Also, terrorism hasn't been "defeated" (a nonsense statement when you think about it), from recent US intelligence agencies statements, and alt-right domestic terrorism seems to be on the rise (remember those bombs sent through the mail).

Comment: *"If you don't believe the US government, who else would you believe? Venezuela? Russia? China?"* No, no, and no. What a silly selection of options. Why do I have to believe any government? Why can't I believe facts and evidence instead?

Comment: @CrackpotCrocodile The US government lead by Trump gave you offical views on facts and evidence, but you don’t believe them but only yourself?

Comment: @CrackpotCrocodile Obama economy was struggling, house price was down, credit crisis, financial crisis, Wall Street had problems. Facts. Trump solved the problem. The economy is much stronger than before. Facts. Trump doesn’t have to help the financial sector. Please think for facts.

Comment: @SmallChess ... and there it is. You can't *think* a fact into existence. Facts come from research and evidence. Also, you are describing Bush's economy. There is a significant delay factor on president's actions impact on the economy, and the [financial crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_crisis_of_2007%E2%80%932008) started in 2007 (definitely Bush). Obama's economy continued strong into the next administration, where the grown declined or reversed in many areas.

Comment: @SmallChess No, Obama solved the economic problems started under Bush years before Trump ever even ran for office.

Comment: @CrackpotCrocodile I'm not sure what economic indicators you were looking at, but the U.S. stock market was almost completely flat for the two years preceding Trump's election. In the 15 months following election day, the DJIA shot up 49% and the S&P500 by 38%. The economy is indeed doing significantly better since Obama left office, though that's more due to not being impaired as much by government policy than to actually being helped by any particular government policy. The dramatic increases in the markets in those 15 months had nothing to do with Obama's policies, aside from their ending.

Comment: (For the record, I despise Trump, voted against him, and plan to do so again if he seeks reelection, but asserting that the strong economy of the last couple of years was somehow due to Obama is just wrong.)

Comment: @reirab Thanks for clarification. If users here don't like my answer, please just follow Phlipp's suggestion; vote it down and then move on. There is no need to attack me words by words.

Comment: @reirab Don't conflate the stock market with the economy. Almost half of Americans have literally nothing invested in the stock market. Stocks are primarily owned by the rich, which is perhaps why the rich like to point to the stock market as their favorite economic indicator. If the rich were given a bunch of money in the form of a tax break (or anticipated it), they might do stock buybacks which could inflate the stock market value without benefit to most of the economy... Which is actually what happened.

Comment: @CrackpotCrocodile GDP growth is up, too. Unemployment is near the lowest it has been since the early 1970s. [Inflation-adjusted median household income is at its all-time high.](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/?g=lGHP) (Not average, mind you, but median, which is completely unaffected by the wealthy.) Also, the stock market increase was before the tax cut went into effect (2018 was the first year it was in effect.)

Comment: @reirab *"GDP growth is up"* [GDP looks pretty erratic to me](https://www.statista.com/statistics/188185/percent-chance-from-preceding-period-in-real-gdp-in-the-us/). You switched to talking about unemployment in absolute terms. It has been on a downward trend since 2010, with a noticeable slowing in the last 2 years ([chart](https://data.bls.gov/timeseries/lns14000000)). Currently it has climbed back up to where it was last March. Why would a company have to wait for the tax cut to actually go into effect before buying back their stock? It would make no sense to wait around for that.

Comment: You can always throw money at a thing and see some short-term gains, but those short-term artificial gains have a tendency to turn into long-term problems like recessions [1](https://www.politico.com/story/2018/12/07/trump-2020-election-economy-recession-trade-war-1048197) [2](https://www.forbes.com/sites/yuwahedrickwong/2018/11/04/how-donald-trump-is-shaping-the-next-global-economic-recession/) [3](https://www.washingtonpost.com/business/economy/trumps-big-2020-problem-the-economy-could-be-in-recession/2018/11/13/a6a8946a-e695-11e8-b8dc-66cca409c180_story.html).

Comment: @CrackpotCrocodile You really hate your own country, aren't you? You are welcome to vote Trump off in 2020.

Comment: @CrackpotCrocodile I talked about unemployment in percentage terms because it can't go down forever. It's already around the level that economists have historically considered full employment. You can't have more than full employment. The tax cut was passed in late December 2017. Most of the stock market increase had already happened before then. The bill wasn't even introduced until Nov 2017. The stock market rise started immediately after Clinton's loss (literally the next day.)

Comment: @SmallChess Actually, it is because I love my country, that I will vote Trump off in 2020. I would hate to see it trashed further.

Comment: @reirab *"literally the next day"* In other words, it started fully in anticipation of tax cuts, with no need to wait until they were actually passed (when the price would be higher). Thanks for proving my point!